# laravel - How to trim a video without converting it in laravel-ffmpeg

Tags: php, laravel, video, ffmpeg

I have an MP4 video and I want to take 1 minute from it. When I do this with other types like WMV it will convert and trim it correctly because the formats are different. However when I want to trim MP4 it doesn't because even for trimming I should set the format and convert it as MP4 and the video will be corrupted.

My code is:

```
FFMpeg::fromDisk('local')
    ->open($filePath.$fileName)
    ->addFilter($clip)
    ->export()
    ->toDisk('local')
    ->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame', 'libx264'))
    ->save($converted);
```

As I said it will work for other types than MP4 but not MP4 itself. It destroys the file for less than 1 second.

How can I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: if the mp4 file longer than 1 minute, the problem still exists?

Comment: @Ben Yes there is no difference!! it doesn't convert and destroy the video for only less than 1 second.

Comment: how about if you try `aac` instead of `libmp3lame`?

Comment: I don't know what happened but now it doesn't even clip the video even after change it back to libmp3lame

Comment: what ffmpeg version are you using?

Comment: ffmpeg version N-90454-g10d008f0fd Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers

Comment: libavutil      56. 12.100 / 56. 12.100
libavcodec     58. 16.100 / 58. 16.100
libavformat    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
libavdevice    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
libavfilter     7. 13.100 /  7. 13.100
libswscale      5.  0.102 /  5.  0.102
libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100